# How to change number of comb boxes dynamically using visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am using visual Basic. On my form I have a text box and a button. User will enter an integer in text box when click button, program will add that many number of combo boxes on the form. My problem is if I change the number in text box bigger than the existing one, my program will give me correct number of combo boxes on the form.  However, if the new number if less than the existing number, my program does reduce number of combo boxes on the form. For example if I have 5 combo boxes already on my form and I enter 10 in text box followed by click the button, I will get correct number of combo boxes.  But If I change number from 10 to 6, my program does not show me 6 combo boxes, it keep showing me 10.

Can anyone help me how to correct this issue in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can put 10 combobox and hide the one that are not being used 
Example if the user input 7, combobox 8,9 and 10 can be hidden by doing this

```
combobox.visible = false
```

To make it even easier you can make an array of combobox and loop trough it

```
Dim comboboxArray() = As Combobox = {combobox1, combobox2, combobox3, _
combobox4, combobox5, combobox6, combobox7, combobox8, combobox9, _
combobox10}
'number is the value in the textbox change the variable to what you have
if number < 10 then
    for i as integer = 9 To number step -1
        comboboxArray(i).visible = false
    next i 
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear out the old controls before you add the new ones.

Here's an example using a FlowLayoutPanel which arranges the controls for you automatically:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim strInput As String = TextBox1.Text
    If Integer.TryParse(strInput, x) Then
        If x > 0 Then
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
            For i As Integer = 1 To x
                Dim cb As New ComboBox
                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cb)
            Next
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an Integer Greater Than Zero.", "Invalid Number of Comboboxes!")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Integer: " & strInput, "Invalid Integer!")
    End If
End Sub
```